# Correct implementation of Factory pattern in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, implementation

I have a question about correct way of implementing factory pattern in PHP used for instantiating complex objects with their dependencies. Let's assume the factory class has a 'build' method, so that for example class User is created in following way:

```
$factory->build('User');
```

The class User needs to retrieve the user data from the repository (database), so it depends on Repository object - the constructor looks like:

```
public function __construct(Repository $repository);
```

This means that 'build' method of the factory needs to call something like this

```
$user = new User(new Repository());
```

Now let's assume I also need to instantiate HomeController object which displays content on the home page. It is retrieving a list of latest articles - to display them on the home page, so it needs repository object as well. So build method will call something like this:

```
$home = new HomeController(new Repository());
```

So it is clear now that we have two instances of Repository object, while in fact one instance would be probably enough in this case. So I was wondering if it is a good practise for factory pattern to actually register instantiated Repository object (store it in $registeredObjects array of Factory object) and return it from the table if it was instantiated before. So the object creation in build method would look then like so:

```
$user = new User($this->build('Repository'));  // Here Repository is created first time.
$home = new HomeController($this->build('Repository'));  //Here it is retrieved from list of already registered objects
```

Repository object act in fact as a singleton in this case. I am wondering whether this approach is correct or it is better to instantiate two independent Repository objects.

Comment: You're right, the User is supposed to manage typical user stuff: login/logout process, display User profile, etc. But the user data needs to be retrieved from some repository, that's why User needs Repository object injected. Now: should I create new Repository object each time either User or HomeController is created? Or should Repository object be in fact a singleton - while factory creates User object it sees Repository needs to be injected. So factory checks and sees: "OK I have already created Repository which was needed for different object, so I can inject the existing one here as well"

Comment: I don't understand what your point is, I am afraid. I am not confusing static methods, I am not even using them. Also I am not going to "tell" the User about Repository or Factory. All I am asking for, is when creating new User, should I inject already existing Repository object or create a new one?

Comment: Inject the repository into what exactly? I understand the controller needing a user repository. I am confused as  to why the `User` needs one? i.e .The `User` is an 'output'  from the repository when fetching. And accepts one when storing. Which tutorial did you get this from? Please post a link. Are you making a `user repository`? Do you have a class for the repository that I can look at?

Comment: Do you expect the User to be able to 'save' or 'store' itself? i.e. `$user->save();`? Please don't do that.